# Graph api Request token without user

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to use the graph API to eventually automatically create a Microsoft Teams meeting where you can join with the URL. But before I can do this I need to get a bearer token. Because I want to create a meeting without the use of a user I need to use this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service. I've followed this documentation and first tried something in postman but that failed so I tried to do it in node.js. This my code now:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
fetch("https://login.microsoftonline.com/f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({"client_id":"CLIENT_ID",
    "scope":"https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default",
"client_secret":"CLIENT_SECRET",
"grant_type":"client_credentials"
})}).then((reposone)=>{
    console.log(reposone)
}
);
```

I'm not sure what would be confidential, so I just changed the client_id and client_secret to words. I got the client_id from Azure at the overview tab in the register application next to the "Application (client) id". And the client_secret is from the certificate & secrets tab where I generate a secret. If I execute this code with the values inserted I get a 404 response, so I don't see what I'm exactly doing wrong. I'm guessing my URL is wrong but I have no idea what else it could be. I got the tenant id in the url from the overview tab next to "Directory (tenant) ID".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out there are a lot of things I did wrong. First the URL is "https://login.microsoftonline.com/f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a/oauth2/v2.0/token" and not with the HTTP/1.1 added. Secondly, my active directory configuration was wrong. I needed to recreate it so that I was an admin. Lastly, I needed to configure my application to receive other accounts than just Microsoft account or else I could not give application permissions for my API.

Answer (score 0):

You would have a couple of choices, depending on your design.

I assume you will use the "POST /me/onlineMeetings" method. Your App Registration will need the OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite permission for Delegated access and OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All for Application access. Your app Registration may also have additional permissions to sign in a user etc.

If you choose Application access, you will obtain your OAuth2 access token from the V2.0 endpoint by using the "client_credentials" grant type along with your client_id and client_secret. You should then be able to create a Teams meeting by providing a objectid or upn instead of "me" in the url above.

If you choose Delegated access, you should preferably use the access token from the already signed in user. But if that doesn't work, you could get an access token by using the "password" grant type along with your client_id and the username+password of a resource owner user. Please note that the password flow is not a recommend way to do things. You can hit a number of problems, like password change, permissions change, two factor authentication and  it's not considered secure. When having the access token, you can create the Teams meeting with the url above. The meeting organizer will probably be the resource owner.

Comment: My problem is not with creating a meeting. My problem is the OAuth2 flow itself. When I send a https://login.microsoftonline.com/f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1 post request like you suggested then I get a 404. So nothing about the body, even though https://login.microsoftonline.com/f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a/oauth2 doesn't give a 404 error but this is not a valid endpoint because I get the login page as response.

Comment: Here's the doc for the "password" grant type: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc and here's for the "client_credentials" grant type: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow  None of these should present a user UI as they are POST with a content request.